# What is the SHA-1 of 255?

Tags: utf-8, sha1

Assume you have a sha-1 algorithm that accepts text as input instead of a byte array. 
(For instance there are some Javascript libraries like that).

When you would like to apply sha-1 to a text (let's say the text is a password), then you first do a utf-8 encoding because the text can contain multi-byte characters. In other words, the corresponding integer value of a character in the text can be larger than an 8-bit byte can hold. Since the sha-1 algorithm works on 8-bit units, it helps to encode the text in utf-8 first.

My question is this:
When you have a non-textual binary data where the value of each byte is between 0 and 255, are you still expected to do utf-8 encoding on the binary data before you pass it to the sha-1 algorithm? I know that when the values are between 0 and 127, utf-8 does not modify the data at all.

However, if the values are between 128 and 255, the UTF-8 modifies such data.

In summary, here is my question: What is SHA-1 of the byte containing the value 255 (all 1's)?

```
With UTF-8 encoding:    730cf30d408ecf51aad876f5c491f837f7ddea4c

Without UTF-8 encoding: 85e53271e14006f0265921d02d4d736cdc580b0b
```

Which one is the right one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, don't UTF-8 encode binary data, it makes no sense. If you want a hash of a piece of binary  data, you should SHA-1 *exactly that*, not some random transformation of that data.

You shouldn't UTF-8 encode strings either unless what you want is the SHA-1 of the *UTF-8 representation of that string*.

Comment: If it is that clear, why all the javascript libraries I have come across on the web does UTF-8 encoding first? see these two: [http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html) and [http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.sha1.js.txt](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.sha1.js.txt)

Comment: It's a "normalization" method. Say you have two users who send you "hé" in a message. One user sends it in ISO-8859-1, the other in UTF-16. If what you want to compare is the bytes they sent you (2 bytes in the first, 4 in the second), don't do any transformation on the input before hashing. If what you want to compare is the text ("human understandable") content, choose one encoding, encode all your inputs to that "canonical" encoding, and compare the hash of that common representation.

Comment: My question is "do we do the normalization or not for sha1"? If we do not, why do the libraries do it?

Comment: Normalization is (usually) a good idea for textual data. But it **makes no sense** at all for binary data. Passing a binary through an UTF-8 encoding scheme (what would you choose as source encoding) doesn't normalize it at all (it corrupts it). You seem to think that chars "above 127" have a special role for SHA - that is not the case. The SHA-1 of a binary file with one single byte with all bits set is 85e... Your other sum is the SHA1 of some completely different thing that has not meaning.

Comment: I understand your answer and I am about to close the question but could you tell me your opinion on why then the javascript sha1 libraries do utf-8 encoding by default? Note that there is no byte data structure in javascript. Therefore, you have to represent your binary data as text to pass it to sha-1 javascript code because string is the only data type such libraries support as input.

Comment: That has more to do with how Javascript Strings are implemented. `charCodeAt` gives you a unicode codepoint (more or less) in the 0..65535 range. SHA-1 works on byte arrays. So implementing SHA-1 without first transforming the String to an 'array of bytes' would be much more difficult. The utf8 transforms in the code you linked above do that - transform the Javascript String types to 'array of bytes', using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I realized that my initial statement about a byte having values between 128 and 255 is wrong if the bytes I am dealing with are signed. Since a signed byte can never have a value between 128 and 255, when I say 255, I realized that I actually mean -1.

Comment: I solved my problem. I found a SHA1-javascript implementation that treats an input as binary if its constructor is not string. I passed an array with 255 in it ([255]) and the javascript library was able to produce 85e53271e14006f0265921d02d4d736cdc580b0b. I also verified this using a Java implementation that accepts byte arrays. In that one I provided a byte array with -1 in it ({-1}) which is 255 if you treat bytes signed. Java also produced the same number. Result:NO UTFencoding should be done and the sha1 library should provide you the option not to preprocess the data before computation.